# Password Protect specific Win10 Applications?

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, passwords, password-protection

i have my personal Win10 PC unlocked, in case my girlfriend needs to use a real PC instead of her oldschool Notebook. I use some apps like Telegram or WhatsApp on my Windows machine, which i dont want her to be able to open just like that. is there a way to password-protect certain apps? I found some apps that offer a service like that but, i dont know how to say it, they seem weird. Anyone got a recommendation? like an app, where the shortcuts are still on my desktop and stuff, but before opening, you have to enter short passphrase or similar.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
since my GF is not a techhead, it does not have to be a super secure method. a seperate windows account is also not an option, because then it would seem super suspicious if i all over sudden set up obvious barriers like an account PW, she might think i have secrets. i just dont want her to be able to read all my messages and im tired of logging out of messengers and so on everyday. (also if you need to know: i dont think she would do something like that, ever. but better safe than sorry)

Comment: Why can't you create another account/user for her? Like that she won't have access at your personal data.

Comment: the thing is - i dont want to. shes my girlfriend, and if i start setting up obvious barriers like a account password on windows after over 3 years of relationship shes gonna wonder why. there is no specific reason, but im just sick and tired of logging out of whatsapp and telegram everyday (i dont have secrets but i have friends whom i talk to if something bothers me, and that "something" can sometimes be my GF)

Comment: This isn’t about trust or anything. It’s simply about settings/profile separation. That is what accounts are for. Use them.

Comment: you guys are right. everything else would be some whacky solution which would at best just "sort of" work. thanks for your input, i will do that. she will understand, and if she will not, than thats another bigger issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new Windows User Account for your friend and log out of your ID when not using it.

It is not possible to password protect Applications in general. Also, locking (password protect) all your documents is troublesome.

A new and separate Windows user account is vastly the best way to solve this issue.

Separate User Accounts allow: Separate email, separate documents, separate favorites, and (largely, done right) separate apps.

Same user account allows same apps, same document store and (done right) two Outlooks on the same desktop. Users need to be aware of the trust issues involved.

Both ways work. In general, separate user accounts cover more situations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that is not an option, please see the 2nd comment of my original post. in general, yea, thats the solution, but if i set up an an account password suddenly after 3 yrs of relationship, shes gonna wonder why and i dont want her wondering if i have something to hide

Comment: I understand your response. Discuss first to see what happens. If you try to preclude access to apps, your friend will notice that as well with the same reaction. Discuss first and come to agreement. User accounts are very normal for Windows Users. This would allow her to have her own documents. Also her own email, favorites and other personal things.

Comment: you guys are right. thats the only permanent and correct solution. thanks for setting me straight, i wasnt thinking correct on this one.

Comment: You are very welcome and good luck with your situation. All should be well if you discuss with your friend.